# How can I remove the LSI MegaRaid BIOS from a Z800?

Tags: bios

At one point in my workstation's life there was an LSI SAS card attached for DLT backups but that's long gone. I've tried flashing the bios using a USB card, resetting the CMOS, but the startup LSI messages don't go away. How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LSI (SAS) controller is built into the motherboard; disable it via the BIOS.

[From HP](http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/downloads/MWP_RiversRAID_3-13-2009.pdf):

> On the Z800 platform SAS RAID is supported using the **on-board** LSI Logic 1068E controller and the LSI Logic MegaRAID SAS 8888ELP HBA.

That system/motherboard also has an Intel Matrix RAID controller on it (for SATA); so you may only be able to switch from one to the other, and not disable them both completely.

Check the `Storage > Storage Options` section of your BIOS.

See here for more info on [setting up RAID on an z800](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c01722374).